# Python CSV File For loops and date comparison

Tags: python, csv

Hey Guys i'm new and learning python and I feel like i'm a little out of my league with this question. I'm looking advice on how to handle.

I have a main csv file main.csv with contains many fields, but the four important ones are ID, Name, Date , and Status. Just to clarify, the name and ID fields are NOT UNIQUE. The same ones will appear on multiple lines.

I'm trying to use a for loop to go through the main file and break out the findings by Name and ID and in each unique case I want to compare the dates and pick the one furthest in the future.

I got this far and now i'm struggling. Below is my script and output so far

Script

---

```
import csv

s=open('combined.csv')
mainfile = csv.reader(s)

id = ['1','4']
Name = ['Anthony', 'Bob']
Status = ['New', 'Old']

for r in mainfile:
    for m in Name:
        for t in id:
            if r[10] in (None, ""):
                pass
            elif r[3] == m:
                if r[5] == t:
                    print (r[3], r[5], r[6], r[11])
```

---

Output example:

```
('Anthony', '1', '10', '4/3/2017')
('Anthony', '1', '11', '5/2/2017')
('Anthony', '1', '13', '12/30/2017'
('Anthony', '1', '15', '8/20/2017')
('Anthony', '4', '17', '2/3/2018')
('Anthony', '4', '18', '3/28/2017')
('Bob', '1', '111', '4/3/2017')
('Bob', '1', '200', '5/2/2017')
('Bob', '1', '113', '12/30/2017')
('Bob', '1', '115', '8/20/2017')
('Bob', '4', '117', '2/3/2018')
('Bob', '4', '118', '3/28/2017')
```

I'm getting hung up because I not want to look where the Name and ID fields are unique and compare all of those dates and return the one furthest in the future for each then print that out to a file.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What if there's a Charles in the file?

Comment: The Name list is going to be populated prior so the only names in the output will be what I already define in that list. I'm just testing right now, but in the end there will be 26ish unique names

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `datetime` with `.strptime` method and `sorted` with `key` argument.

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_date(date):
    return datetime.strptime('%m/%d/%Y', date)

ids = ('1', '4')
names = ('Anthony', 'Bob')
lines = []

with open('combined.csv', 'r', newline='') as s:
    mainfile = csv.reader(s)

    for r in mainfile:
        if r[10] and r[3] in names and r[5] in ids:
            lines.append((r[3], r[5], r[6], r[11]))

lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda line: get_date(line[3]))

for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Something like this. Not tested.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 21, in <module>
    lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda line: get_date(line[3]))
  File "new.py", line 21, in <lambda>
    lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda line: get_date(line[3]))
  File "new.py", line 6, in get_date
    return datetime.strptime('%-m/%-d/%Y', date)
  File "H:\Anaconda2\lib\_strptime.py", line 332, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '%-m/%-d/%Y' does not match format '4/3/2017'

Comment: I'm getting an error because the months under 10 should have 0 and they don't. Can the function be modified so it doesn't look for that?

Comment: Thyrst,  I was looking at your code more and I don't think this is going work because i'm looking for multiple lines to be returned not just one. Meaning Everything the Name and ID fields match I want to look at all dates and pull the latest. That means in my example code above there should be 4 rows returned. Anthony-1, Anthony-4, Bob-1, and Bob-4

Comment: @Anthony I see. You could for example use dict with tuple(name, id) as a key. Then you just check inside for cycle if there is already this key and if current date is greater than the date in the value. :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Tuple and i'm guess I do some sort of for loop that compares down the csv file where name and id is the same? i'm not seeing how you get the output though.